# Do axis rotate on glrotate?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a sphere that I am translating into the middle of, then I would like to be able look around in that spehere.

I notice that rotation works around the y axis perfectly, and rotation works around the x axis great at the initial viewing angle, but when I rotate 90 right on the y axis, and then try to rotate again on the x axis, the sphere rotates in a rolling fashion instead of a looking up and down.

This behavior leads me to believe that the axis do not change when you rotate. Do I need to have a special call to reset the axis once my rotation is complete?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock).

The relevant wikipedia article has some solutions, e.g. [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions).